# How to hide output from net use in Powershell

Tags: networking, powershell, output, net-use

I'm using this Powershell script to connect a network path:

```
$usrLogin = [Environment]::UserName + "@mydomain.net"
$cred = Get-Credential $usrLogin
$networkCred = $cred.GetNetworkCredential()
$usercred = $networkCred.UserName + '@' + $networkCred.Domain
$extractSource = "\\srv01\d$\"
net use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred
```

I decide to use "net use", because I'll open later in the Script a FileDialog which opens directly the Network Path.

```
$openFileDialog1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$openFileDialog1.initialDirectory = "\\srv01\d$\"
```

Now my question:

How can I hide the output from the "net use" command? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
net use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred | out-null
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redirect the error stream to null:

```
net use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred 2>null
```

Or use 2>&1 to redirect the error stream to the standard output stream and both to null:

```
net use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred 2>&1>null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I was looking for! I've allways tought i need to use a pipe instad of a ">" :-)

Comment: Can you please explain what 2>&1>null is doing?  How does redirecting a number handle errors?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. These numbers represent console streams, 2 is the error stream. You can find more information in the about_Redirection help topic

Answer (score 1):

The line above works when I run it(piping to `out-null`). if it still doesn't work for you, try the following:

```
(net use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred) | out-null
```

or storing in $null like this:

```
$null = net use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred
```

Comment: Unfortunately both options do not work for me... It hides only a success message from the "net use" command but not Error warnings. Per example when i run the command twice I get still a Error like this even I pipe it to out-null: 
net.exe : System error 1219 has occurred.
At line:133 char:16
+                 $null = net <<<<  use $extractSource $networkCred.Password /USER:$usercred
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (System error 1219 has occurred.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource...

Comment: This is something you should have specified in the question. To handle error output, see Shay's answer.

Comment: Sorry for the uncertain question... Thank you anyway!